# How to handle error in Node.js URL Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I wanted to use a function to extract part of a URL in Node, and would like to also use it to validate data.

Here is the documentation or the [`url` module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html), and here is my function:

```
function getHostname(url) {
  var website = new URL(url);
  return website.hostname;
}
```

The problem comes when the URL received is not valid, how would I handle the error the situation such that in that case it would return the original string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a try/catch statement:

```
function getHostname(url) {
  try {
    var website = new URL(url);
    return website.hostname;
  } catch(error) {
    if(error instanceof TypeError) {
      return url;
    } //just to check if TypeError, probably not necessary for your use
  }
}
```

Since a TypeError is raised with a bad URL, you can catch it.